# Sacar diagonal principaly secundaria [Duda con condicional]

Tags: javascript, matrices

estaba realizando un ejercicio para sacar las diagonales de una matriz y pues he logrado sacar la diagonal principal porque pues es cuando las posiciones coinciden (1,1) (2,2), etc. Pero, para encontrar la diagonal secundaria se me ha hecho dificil elobrarlo, pero encontre un condicional que la saca y no entiendo el como funciona y porque, este es mi codigo.

```
let arr = [
  [11, 2, 4],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [10, 8, -12],
];
let diagonalUno = 0;
let diagonalDos = 0;
let resultado = 0;

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
    if (i == j) {
      diagonalUno += arr[i][j];
    }
    console.log("======================");
    if (i + j == arr.length - 1) {
      diagonalDos += arr[i][j];
    }
  }
}
resultado = Math.abs(diagonalUno - diagonalDos);
console.log("RESULTADO: " + resultado);
```

Espero puedan explicarme, se los agradeceria

Answer (score 0):

creo que de pensar un poquito más encontré esta explicación, creo que es correcta

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]